# Django admin does not show extra fields added in init method of modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I found a couple of questions regarding this, but I specifically wonder about how to add a field in the `ModelForm`s `__init__()` method.

This is, because I get the number of fields from a function and need to display them in the admin:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["name", "price",]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number_of_fields = get_number of fields(kwargs["instance"])
        print(number_of_fields) ## e.g. 3, gives output
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(number_of_fields):
            self.fields[i] = forms.CharField("test", required = False)
```

But the fields do not show up in the Template Admin edit page. What did I miss? No error popping up either ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... but you need to pass field name into `self.base_fields['name_of_the_field']` somehow

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["name", "price",]
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number_of_fields = get_number_of_fields(kwargs["instance"])
        print(number_of_fields) ## e.g. 3, gives output
        
        for i in range(number_of_fields):
            self.base_fields['name_of_the_field'] = forms.CharField(initial="test", required = False)
        
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But what is the error message?

Comment: This was very bad copy&paste from me: The error message is: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` - it refers to the row with `self.base_fields ...`.

Comment: On which line? If on this `super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` then try getting rid of *args and **kwargs

Comment: no this one: `self.base_fields['name_of_the_field'] = forms.CharField("test", required = False)`.

Comment: Hmmmm.... try `forms.CharField(initial="test", required = False)`

Comment: little success: The error is gone, but the field is still not visible in the admin.

Comment: Ok. Now I think we need to find a way to add new fields names in `Meta.fields`. Can you test what happens if you comment out `fields`  from `class Meta`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242111/discussion-between-xtlc-and-bartosz-stasiak).

Comment: I get this error when removing `fields` from meta: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form LayoutAdminForm needs updating`.